# Laravel 5 Before Retrived Event

Tags: laravel, events

I'm using laravel 5.6

I have a User Model and too its migration and I migrated it up.

I have some data in users table.

When I want to retrieve my user list like these:

```
User::get();
User::all();
User::where('created_at', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->get();
```

or in another way,

I need these query to **don't show** the **id 1**

I want every query doesnt show the id 1, not manually

What should I do?

I looked at events and another things, please give an example code or clean describe, not to refer to a link.

Comment: what you need is [Query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: More specifically, [a global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes).

Answer (score 0):

```
User::where('id', '!=', User::first()->id)->where('created_at', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->get();
```

Comment: OP is after a solution for every query, without having to specify it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using laravel Anonymous Global Scopes,

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('id', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('id', '!=', 1);
        });
    }
}
```

Or you can use Global Scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes